Count rows from combining two tables
What Postgres query can I use for the below scenario?
Parent table:

Child table:

Expected result

Explanation:
Parent1 --> 4 equipments. Parent1 has ...

Child1 holding 3 equipment
Child2 holding 1 equipment

Parent2 --> 3 equipments. Parent2 has ...

Child3 holding 2 equipment
Child4 holding 1 equipment


Please remember to post data as text, not as image.

Basically, aggregate after joining:
SELECT p.parent AS name, count(*)
FROM   parent p
JOIN   child  c USING (name)
GROUP  BY p.parent
ORDER  BY p.parent;

Nuances of the query depend on undisclosed details.
Like, to include parents with no equipment, and optimize performance for possibly many rows per child, use a LEFT JOIN, and aggregate counts per child before the join:
SELECT p.parent AS name, sum(c.ct) AS count
FROM   parent p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT c.name, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   child c
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (name)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1

